# Генерация формы на лету

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется следующая проблема (см ссылку https://jsfiddle.net/60h1mcL9/)

Ниже привожу часть скрипта:

```
$(function() {
$("#btn1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert('qweqw');
    $('#ff').submit();
});

$("#form2").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/bad-feedback",
        data: "msg=MMSSGG",
        success: function () {
        }
    });
});
```

После отправки сообщения скриптом генерируется форма `form2` с одной кнопкой `btn1`. По нажатию на нее я хочу получить алерт, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: где создается кнопка с таким идентификатором `#btn1` ?

Comment: Добавляйте обработчик там, где Вы добавляете HTML код с btn1. 
P.S.: в следующий раз старайтесь оформить ответ с кодом в одном месте, а то у Вас получается часть кода здесь, а часть на jsFiddle.

Comment: Отправить весь код через jsFiddle не получилось из-за правил stackoverflow. Пришлось скопировать часть в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - читать весь dom и ловить клик на `#btn1`

```
$(document).on('click','#btn1', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.alert('qweqw');
    $('#ff').submit();
});
```

Минус - чтение всего древа... Можно ещё функцию написать для отправки и добавить её в кнопку через `onclick="function()"`
Для кнопки добавляем `onclick`:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn1" onclick="clickMe()">
```

И сама функция:

```
function clickMe(){
    window.alert('qweqw');
    $('#ff').submit();
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Единственное у меня не получается перейти к отправки ajax запроса на /bad-feedback. Согласно Вашему решению, запрос идет на /. Мне требуется написать кастомную функцию submit?

P.S. У меня получилось корректно отправить запрос, прочитав весь dom и отловив клик, но мне не нравится такое решение.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает мое изначальное решение? В чем возникает проблема

Comment: Не работает так как изначально загружается скрипт который считывает dom в котором не существует эл-та с #btn1, соответственно, событие вешать некуда, приведенный мною код при каждом клике считывает dom заново - после добавления в нём уже будет ваш эл-т. 
Я для этого привёл вам пример с функцией через onclick. Так тоже будет работать и при этом не будет считываться dom.

Comment: А чтоб запрос шел куда вам нужно - надо или вот это `$('#ff').submit();` поменять так же, как и идёт submit ваш тут `$("#form2").submit(function(e) {...});` или же, добавить в форму `action="/bad-feedback" ` если вам не нужна отправка через ajax.